# I can't connect to server using curl

Tags: php, json, curl

When I try to send request to the server in localhost I receive this message :

> Error: call to URL
>   https://wasl.elm.sa/WaslPortalWeb/rest/DriverRegistration/send failed
>   with status 200, response {"resultCode":503,"resultMessage":"Yakeen
>   Failure: The ID Is Not Found at
>   NIC","referenceNumber":0,"valid":false}, curl_error , curl_errno 0

On the live server I receive this message :

> string(171) "{"apiKey":"My api
>   key","captainIdentityNumber":"12355567897","dateOfBirth":"15-07-1400","emailAddress":"mo@mo.com","mobileNumber":"966508060095"}"
>   Error: call to URL
>   https://wasl.elm.sa/WaslPortalWeb/rest/DriverRegistration/send failed
>   with status 0, response , curl_error Unknown SSL protocol error in
>   connection to wasl.elm.sa:443 , curl_errno 35

I use this script to make the request:

```
<?php

    //driver registartion url   
    $url = "https://wasl.elm.sa/WaslPortalWeb/rest/DriverRegistration/send";     
    $data=["apiKey"=>"My apikey","captainIdentityNumber"=>"1234567897","dateOfBirth"=>"15-07-1400","emailAddress"=>"mo@mo.com","mobileNumber"=>"966508060095"];
    $content = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    var_dump($content);
    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    var_dump($response);
    ?>
```

my api key it's correct one given by the server owner

Comment: Use postman and see what response you get. I think there is issue with server..

Comment: the data that i entred should be correct i receive success message on localhost but still the same problem on live server.I receive this message {"resultCode":100,"resultMessage":"Success","referenceNumber":56157,"valid":false}, curl_error , curl_errno 0

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Wasl portal, it is not related to curl or connection errors.

You have to contact the portal admins because it is API specific error.